# GWT + Ajax Crawling

Tags: gwt

I am trying to incorporate Ajax Crawling (http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html) with my GWT apps.
The app is a single HTML Page with all content rendered using GWT.
I am using GWT-RPC to communicate with the server and the data is exchanged in the form of serializable POJOs. As such, there are no links in my application pointing to any "servlets".

In such a scenario, how would I go about making my app crawlable?

Comment: Have you seen this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489686/gwt-and-search-engines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT relies on the [MVP (Model-View-Presenter)](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/trunk/ReleaseNotes.html#MvpFramework) pattern and not MVC. Hence, it is perfectly fine (and expected) if you have just a single HTML page where all the views get rendered.

The way to make your GWT app crawlable is to have distinct URLs for each of your views that you wish to get indexed.

One can go about doing this by using the [History mechanism](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/trunk/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html) in GWT ([click here for docs](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/History.html)). ie, For every view, you ought to assign a 'history token' using the [hash-bang notation](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html).

GWT 2.1 also introduces the concept of [Activities](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/activity/shared/package-summary.html) and [Places](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/place/shared/package-summary.html) which you can utilize to compartmentalize your ajax app into logically distinct views, each of which would have their own 'history token' and hence a unique crawable URL.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok. Sounds logical.But in my scenario, there are no URLs. All data exchange is via POJOs. So the question really is how to make the crawlers aware of the POJOs.

Comment: If you found the answer useful, I would really appreciate a vote up! Thanks! :)