# GWT and Search Engines

Tags: gwt, search-engine

Does GWT app are indexed by search engines???? if yes, how to accomplish that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

GWT apps and more generally ajax can't be fully indexed by search engines... [yet](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html). But work is being done to [make ajax applications crawlable](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/). The most common alternative used by developers to get their gwt app referenced is to publish an html version.

Answer (score 0):

Search engines don't prefer html that generated on client side by javascript(Ajax). They prefer static html that generated from server side. That is why, AJAX applications are difficult to index because they are generated dynamically on the client side.